# Vimeo API: Get License of Video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am thinking about using the Vimeo-API to add some extra information to my embedded Vimeo-Video. I am interested in the description and the license. I can see that there is an simple API and an advaced API and I would rather want to use the simple one. But it seems that information on the license is not included. Is there a way to get the license for a video without using the advanced API?

Thanks
Magda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api) is much easier than the Advanced API. I highly recommend giving it a shot.

This API will provide the license type alongside every video response, and allows you to filter most API requests by licenses.

Comment: Hi Dashron, thanks for your answer. I was just wondering if there is a way to get information on a videos's license without having to get an API key. The simple API seems to be the right thing for me, as I am only using public data. But license information is not provided, right?

Comment: The Simple API does not expose this data, and will not continue to be supported. The new API is very, very easy though. If you can, use one of our official libraries to make it even easier : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries

Comment: OK, than I have a look at it. Thanks.